# Backbone fetching a model: Parsing format in array of objects

Tags: backbone.js, model, fetch

My model in the server-side has an attribute which is an array of objects. In the client-side I'm trying to fetch that model in a backbone's model.

After fetching the model from my server I get this object:

```
{
    round: 17,
    username: bob,
    football_bets: [
        0: { one: true, x: false, two: false },
        1: { one: false, x: false, two: true },
        2: { one: true, x: true, two: false },
    ]
}
```

However, I was expecting something like this:

```
{
    round: 17,
    username: bob,
    football_bets: [
        { one: true, x: false, two: false },
        { one: false, x: false, two: true },
        { one: true, x: true, two: false },
    ]
}
```

I understand that this is something related with how backbone parses the result of a fetch action, but I don't know how I should deal with.

Should I override the parse method of the model to get the result as I expect?

Should I use collections instead of trying to model everything inside of a single model?

Should I use some third-party library to deal with nested objects?

I really appreciate any kind of suggestions!

Comment: I think in the first case football_bets is an object?

Comment: No, it is an array of objects

Comment: But you have keys for each object in the football_bets in the first case. And if it is an array of objects I guess 1st and 2nd cases are identical.

Comment: In the first case for instance, it's not possible to access to a property object doing whatever[0].name. I don't know if maybe I missunderstanding something ...

Comment: Can your create a fiddle with that response?

Comment: Sorry it was a big confusion, You were right both arrays are the same. I'm going to explain my mistake in the response. Thanks anyway dude!

Answer (score 0):

The format google-chrome console adopts for arrays is like the first array I've posted in the question. I was thinking that the numbers appears before the object itself was something that backbone it was adding when you perform a fetch action ... I was thinking this because when I debugged my code I had an error that said me it was not possible to access to an attribute.

After more debugging I realize that there was an indexation problem trying to access to an undefined element ... So the conclusion of all this mess is how the google-chrome console formats arrays! Hope this helps somebody ...